# VBA Sub to add row from one table to check multiple tables of line items for qty > 0 and then dynamically add to new table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm have various tables stacked on top of each other forming various product offerings to sell. Within each table are offerings related to that group (think grocery and Produce might be the title of the table and then below that lettuce, tomatoes, cabbage, etc as headers with one header being qty - the first column). I want to iterate through each table and for each table that has a qty > 0 print the title of the table and only rows that have a qty>0.

My thought below was to iterate through each table (starting with table1) and if the qty>0, then copy that row into a dynamically created table, add the rows then mark a global flag as true. If true then paste the title, headers, then the created table. I don't know how to add rows to the table though....

Sub CopyRows()

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Summary")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sales Ops Ready - Rob")
Dim checkFlag As Boolean
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim globalRowCount As Long

Dim objTable As ListObject
Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)

Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

For rw = 1 To lo.Range.Rows.Count
    
    If lo.DataBodyRange(rw, 1) > 0 Then
        checkFlag = True
        ??
    End If
    

Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough idea of how it can be done without knowing your exact requirements.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rw As ListRow
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim objTable As ListObject
    
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
    
    For Each rw In lo.ListRows
        If rw.Range(1) > 0 Then 'set the column index here
            Set newRow = objTable.ListRows.Add
            With newRow
                .Range(1) = rw.Range(1)
                .Range(2) = rw.Range(2)
                '... ... etc
            End With
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I think I'm getting there. I do have another question. How can I set up a new empty table (ListObject) that I can populate where objTable is above? I want to run the For Each iteration for each table in this pricing guide (the pricing guide has multiple tables where each table specifices products specific to that category. So I need to dynamically create the table and then output it to a new tab (which I'll just need to create a clean slate before running the routine. THank you!

Comment: Technically that should be a new question but instead of setting objTable to an existing table, just build a new one using .ListRows.Add and setting objTable to nothing after you are done with it.